# xpath parse table in bash

Tags: bash, csv, xpath, xmllint

I have a html table which I would like to parse out with bash 
(Note: I have used R to do this but would like to attempt in bash to easily integrate with another shell script).

The table can be obtained from the url below:
http://faostat.fao.org/site/384/default.aspx

By reviewing source - the xpath reference for the specific table is:

```
//*[@id="ctl03_DesktopThreePanes1_ThreePanes_ctl01_MDlisting"]
```

How can I parse out this table to a csv file from bash directly?

I tried the following:

```
curl "http://faostat.fao.org/site/384/default.aspx" | xpath '//*[@id="ctl03_DesktopThreePanes1_ThreePanes_ctl01_MDlisting"]' > test.txt
```

This only returns a blank text for test.txt.

Could anyone please help me in parsing out the valid html table using xpath in bash and creating a CSV file of it?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I managed to do the following: `wget -q -O - "http://faostat.fao.org/site/384/default.aspx" | xmllint --html --xpath '//*[@id="ctl03_DesktopThreePanes1_ThreePanes_ctl01_MDlisting"]' - 2>/dev/null > test.txt` but this does not give a CSV output. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`//*[@id="ctl03_DesktopThreePanes1_ThreePanes_ctl01_MDlisting"]/tr` (that is, with `/tr` appended to the XPath expression you had in your question) will grab just each row, and skip the `table` wrapper (which you don’t need to do anything with in your output).

Then you also need to pipe that `xmllint --xpath` output through `sed` or `perl` or something:

**Example: perl version**

```
wget -q -O - "http://faostat.fao.org/site/384/default.aspx" \
   | xmllint --html \
     --xpath '//*[@id="ctl03_DesktopThreePanes1_ThreePanes_ctl01_MDlisting"]/*' - \
     2>/dev/null \
   | perl -pe 's/<tr[^>]+>//' \
   | perl -pe 's/<\/tr>//' \
   | perl -pe 's/^\s+<t[dh][^>]*>//' \
   | perl -pe 's/<\/t[dh]><t[dh][^>]*>/|/g' \
   | perl -pe 's/<\/t[dh]>//' \
   | grep -v '^\s*$'
```

**Example: sed version**

```
wget -q -O - "http://faostat.fao.org/site/384/default.aspx" \
   | xmllint --html \
     --xpath '//*[@id="ctl03_DesktopThreePanes1_ThreePanes_ctl01_MDlisting"]/*' - \
     2>/dev/null \
   | sed -E 's/<tr[^>]+>//' \
   | sed -E 's/<\/tr>//' \
   | sed -E 's/^[[:space:]]+<t[dh][^>]*>//' \
   | sed -E 's/<\/t[dh]><t[dh][^>]*>/|/g' \
   | sed -E 's/<\/t[dh]>//' \
   | grep -v '^\s*$'
```

In both cases, the `grep -v '^\s*$'` is there just to remove blank lines.

It’s not strictly CSV; it separates the fields/cells with a `|` (pipe) character, rather than a comma—because some (many) of the fields themselves also have commas and quotation marks in them. If you really true CSV, than scroll down and read **How to generate true CSV for this case** below.

---

#### Using python and lxml instead

As an alternative to `xmllint --xpath`, you can instead use Python and the `lxml.html` library:

```
wget -q -O - "http://faostat.fao.org/site/384/default.aspx" \
   | python -c "import lxml.html as html; import sys; \
       expr = sys.argv[1]; print '\n'.join([html.tostring(el) \
       for el in html.parse(sys.stdin).xpath(expr)])" \
       '//*[@id="ctl03_DesktopThreePanes1_ThreePanes_ctl01_MDlisting"]//tr' \
   | sed -E 's/<tr[^>]+>//' \
   | sed -E 's/<\/tr>//' \
   | sed -E 's/^[[:space:]]+<t[dh][^>]*>//' \
   | sed -E 's/<\/t[dh]><t[dh][^>]*>/|/g' \
   | sed -E 's/<\/t[dh]>//' \
   | grep -v '^\s*$'
```

---

#### Using the `column` and `colrm` commands to format the output

If you want a pretty-printed/formatted column/table view of the results to read in the console and scroll/page through, pipe the output further into the `column` and `colrm` commands, like this:

```
wget -q -O - "http://faostat.fao.org/site/384/default.aspx" \
   | xmllint --html \
     --xpath '//*[@id="ctl03_DesktopThreePanes1_ThreePanes_ctl01_MDlisting"]/*' - \
     2>/dev/null \
   | sed -E 's/<tr[^>]+>//' \
   | sed -E 's/<\/tr>//' \
   | sed -E 's/^[[:space:]]+<t[dh][^>]*>//' \
   | sed -E 's/<\/t[dh]><t[dh][^>]*>/|/g' \
   | sed -E 's/<\/t[dh]>//' \
   | grep -v '^\s*$' \
   | column -t -s '|' \
   | colrm 14 21 | colrm 20 28 | colrm 63 95 | colrm 80
```

That will give you results like the output just below:

**Results from formatting with `column` and `colrm`**

```
Group Name         Item FAO Code    Item HS+ Code    Item Name      Definition
Crops              800              5304_c           Agave fib      Including int
Crops              221              0802.11_a        Almonds,       Prunus amygda
Crops              711              0909             Anise, ba      Include: anis
Crops              515              0808.10_a        Apples         Malus pumila;
Crops              526              0809.10_a        Apricots       Prunus armeni
…
```

Alternatively, you could use the `cut` command rather than `colrm` to get the same formatting.

---

#### How to generate true CSV

If rather than pretty-printed/formatted output like the above, you really do want real CSV, then you also must emit quotes around the fields, and CSV-escape existing quotes inside fields; like this:

**Example: true CSV output**

```
wget -q -O - "http://faostat.fao.org/site/384/default.aspx" \
   | xmllint --html \
     --xpath '//*[@id="ctl03_DesktopThreePanes1_ThreePanes_ctl01_MDlisting"]/tr' - \
   | sed -E 's/"/""/g' \ 
   | sed -E 's/<tr[^>]+>//' \
   | sed -E 's/<\/tr>//' \
   | sed -E 's/^[[:space:]]+<t[dh][^>]*>/"/' \
   | sed -E 's/<\/t[dh]><t[dh][^>]*>/","/g' \
   | sed -E 's/<\/t[dh]>/"/' \
   | grep -v '^\s*$'
```

Tools that consume CSV apparently expect to see all quotation-mark characters escaped as two quotation-mark characters together; e.g., as the word `""fufu""` is below.

```
  "In West Africa they are consumed mainly as ""fufu"", a stiff glutinous dough."
```

So the `sed -E 's/"/""/g'` part of the code snippet above does that.

**CSV output from the above example**

```
"Group Name","Item FAO Code","Item HS+ Code","Item Name ","Definition"
"Crops","800","5304_c","Agave fibres nes","Including inter alia: Haiti hemp…"
"Crops","221","0802.11_a","Almonds, with shell","Prunus amygdalus; P. communis…"
"Crops","711","0909","Anise, badian, fennel, coriander","Include: anise…"
```

---

#### Disclaimer: You should avoid doing regexp-based processing of HTML/XML

(Obligatory disclaimer) All the above said, many people will tell you regexp-based HTML/XML processing is kludgy+error-prone. And it is, so use the above approach with caution (if at all).

If you have time to do it right, what you should be doing is: **instead use a good Web-scraping library**, or use Python+`lxml` to actually process the results returned from evaluating the XPath expression (instead of stringifying the results), or use **`xsltproc`** or some other XSLT engine.

But you only need something quick-n-dirty from the command line, the above gets the job done.
However, it’s brittle, so don’t be shocked if some part of the output is broken in some unexpected way. **If you want something robust for HTML/XML, don’t use a regexp-based approach** .